# Grid column filter not working with two models in magento custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, module, filter, grid

I'm working with custom module for the magento backend, in this filter not working when using filter calback!
Can anyone suggest me?
Thanks!

*I have tried some codes like this,*

**Grid.php**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
     $collection = Mage::getModel('listings/listings')->getCollection();
     $this->setCollection($collection);
       return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {     
        $this->addColumn("item_id", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("linkmanagement")->__("ID"),
            "align" => "center",
            "type" => "number",
            "index" => "item_id",

        ));

        $this->addColumn("title", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("linkmanagement")->__("Title"),
            "index" => "title"
        ));

        $this->addColumn("cat_ids", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("linkmanagement")->__("Cat ID"),
            "align" => "center",
            "index" => "cat_ids",
            "renderer" => 'Sathish_Linkmanagement_Block_Adminhtml_Linkmanagement_Renderer_Categories',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_categoriesFilter')
        ));

        $this->addColumn("url_key", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("linkmanagement")->__("URL"),
            "index" => "url_key",
            "width" => "200px",
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('linkmanagement')->__('Status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => array('1' => Mage::helper('linkmanagement')->__('Active'),
                    '0' => Mage::helper('linkmanagement')->__('Inactive')),
            )
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

**callback function**

```
protected function _categoriesFilter($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
            "cat_ids ?"
            , "%$value%");
        return $this;
    }
```

**Categories.php**

```
class Sathish_Linkmanagement_Block_Adminhtml_Linkmanagement_Renderer_Categories extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        // $value = 38,92
        $value = explode(',',$value);
        $collection = Mage::getModel("categories/categories")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('category_id',$value)->getData();
        foreach($collection as $col){
            $result[] = $col['title'];
        }
        $result = implode(',', $result);// $result = schools,colleges
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Renderer working fine.,
only filter callback function is not working!!!

Comment: Did you used "'filter_index' => 'id'," attribute for addColumn function?

Comment: @charlie no I use filter_condition_callback

Comment: You just use `'filter_index' => 'cat_id'` and check

Comment: @charlie still it no change

Comment: @Sathish have you got it working? apart from "cat_ids ?" missing "=" (i.e. "cat_ids = ?").

Comment: yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269519/grid-column-filter-not-working-with-two-models-in-magento-custom-module